# Why does my Kotlin app fail to load a Kotlin ServiceWorker script because 'kotlin' was not found?

Tags: kotlin, progressive-web-apps, kotlin-js

I'm writing my first Progressive Web App for some experience with the concept. The web app is written in Kotlin.js and the ServiceWorker is too. When running the app I get this error
`Uncaught Error: Error loading module 'serviceWorker'. Its dependency  'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'serviceWorker'`.

at serviceWorker.js:2`. How and why would 'kotlin' be missing as a dependency, when it is loaded from a kotlin app, that already is using kotlin as a dependency?  given how the application is set up? Is a service worker unable to access the same dependencies as the file loads the service worker?

Answer (score 0):

Service workers operate in their own environment.  A different namespace. The DOM cannot be accessed by a serviceworker, so the none of the definitions from the module loading the service worker are available to the service worker.

One simple solutions is to have a js file with both kotlinjs and the service worker code in the one file.